# Problem with \RequirePackage in documentclass

Tags: luatex, packages, document-classes

Hey Guys I´m using LuaLateX in TeXstudios.

I wanted to export the packages from my .tex into a .cls file to make the .tex file more clear.

In my .tex file I include the .cls file like this:

```
\documentclass[]{Peter}
```

The .cls file looks like this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{Peter}[2022/11/21v. 1.0 me]
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
```

When i compile this it shows many errors from the enumitem.sty file which say for example: "Undefined control sequence. \SetEnumitemSize{script}\scriptsize"

Am I using the \RequirePackage command wrong?

Comment: For some reason `enumitem` assumes that macros like `\scriptsize` have been setup/defiend before loading `enumitem`. Thus, of the code provided is the only contents of your class (aka it is not build upon another class, you'll need to define `\scriptsize` and friends **before** loading `enumitem`.

Comment: I got hit by this myself in a custom letter class.

Comment: Is this only a problem with enumitem, or are there other packages where this is the case?

Comment: No idea. But you should probably have standard stuff like this defined before starting to load packages. If you look at the default classes this is some of the first things they do.

Comment: it is not really related to enumitem, just a general principle that you can not use commands until you define them and `\scriptsize` is not defined by latex, you need to define it in your class

Comment: Various packages expect to be loaded after a class. E.g. hyperref would error too.

Comment: Thank you guys:)

Comment: I can see two basic options to do what you appear to want: make your preamble into a `.sty` file (not a `.cls` file), or look at `\LoadClass` to extend an existing class. I (or someone else) can expand on those options, or search here for questions about creating a class.